# C# string replace

Tags: c#, string, replace, str-replace

I want to replace `","` with a `;` in my string.

For example:

Change

> "Text","Text","Text",

to this:

> "Text;Text;Text",

I've been trying the `line.replace( ... , ... )`, but can't get anything working properly.

Comment: What doesn't work properly?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Try this:

```
line.Replace("\",\"", ";")
```

Answer (score 8):

The simplest way is to do

```
line.Replace(@",", @";");
```

Output is shown as below:

[image]

Comment: This does not answer the question because quotes are not removed.

Answer (score 7):

You need to escape the double-quotes inside the search string, like this:

```
string orig = "\"Text\",\"Text\",\"Text\"";
string res = orig.Replace("\",\"", ";");
```

Note that the replacement does not occur "in place", because .NET strings are *immutable*. The original string will remain the same after the call; only the returned string `res` will have the replacements.

Answer (score 6):

```
var str = "Text\",\"Text\",\"Text";
var newstr = str.Replace("\",\"", ";");
```

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
line.Replace(@""",""", ";");
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you properly escape the quotes.

```
  string line = "\"Text\",\"Text\",\"Text\",";

  string result = line.Replace("\",\"", ";");
```

Answer (score -1):

Set your Textbox value in a string like:

```
string MySTring = textBox1.Text;
```

Then replace your string. For example, replace "Text" with "Hex":

```
MyString = MyString.Replace("Text", "Hex");
```

Or for your problem (replace "," with ;) :

```
MyString = MyString.Replace(@""",""", ",");
```

Note: If you have "" in your string you have to use @ in the back of "", like:

```
@"","";
```

Answer (score -2):

You can't use string.replace...as one string is assigned you cannot manipulate. For that, we use string builder. Here is my example. In the HTML page I add [Name] which is replaced by Name. Make sure [Name] is unique or you can give any unique name:

```
string Name = txtname.Text;
string contents = File.ReadAllText(Server.MapPath("~/Admin/invoice.html"));

StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(contents);

builder.Replace("[Name]", Name);

StringReader sr = new StringReader(builder.ToString());
```

Answer (score -6):

#### Use of the replace() method

Here I'm replacing an old value to a new value:

```
string actual = "Hello World";

string Result = actual.Replace("World", "Stack Overflow");

----------------------
Output : "Hello Stack Overflow"
```