# addslashes C# equivalent

Tags: c#, php, regex, razor

Salaam

I am looking for a proper version of a C# or Razor equivalent of PHP's `addSlashes`. That would add 
`\` to `some\string` => `some\\string`

Please provide help

**Why I needed this**
In my application a user entered Sometext `in textbox` was accidently pressed next time when page when data was populated though Razor it was like this

`...append('<span>'+'@Model.value'+'</span>')`
=> after compiling it becomes like this 
`...append('<span>'+'sometext\'+'</span>')`

so with this scenario my javascript code broke at '\' because now single quote has started but not ending due to ``. So i thought instead of limiting characters i would rather add slashes through C# code

Thank You

Comment: Can you talk us though **why** you want to do this?

Comment: Why is this tagged with javascript and regex?

Comment: @mjwills Thank You for your response in my application a user entered `Sometext \` in textbox `\` was accidently pressed next time when page when data was populated though Razor it was like this  
`...append('<span>'+'@Model.value'+'</span>')`=> after compiling it becomes like this
`...append('<span>'+'sometext\'+'</span>')`

so with this scenario my javascript code broke at `'\'` because now single quote has started but not ending due to `\`. so i thought instead of limiting characters i would rather add slashes through C# code

Comment: @AliJamal Please do not post relevant details of the question in the comments. Edit them to your question, that makes it easier to understand your problem

Comment: I Have tried With This `test / text " '" 12# 2 !@#" @!"#@!"4 @!'4 @!"$"" ?/23 ``'/'\3/[[q//323/54@3/5@#%"@ ?#"` `````""~"~"@~   <> ` String Its Not Working

Answer (score 0):

You don't show any code you've already written, but this can be done by using [string.replace()] ( https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp ) :

```
var str = "This is \\a test";
var replaced = str.replace("\\", "\\\\");
```

Whoops - you want the answer in C# , I misread your "javascript" tag. It's mostly the same:

```
string str = "This is \\a test";
string replaced = str.Replace("\\", "\\\\");
```

Also see [C# String Replace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16839401/c-sharp-string-replace)

After the update, https://stackoverflow.com/a/27574931/34092 is most likely a much better answer.